# Iterate array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects and I need to go through it to get the data and I'm not getting it. I am working with pure javascript.

Solved !!!!!!!

Thanks for the personal help! The array was entering as a string I parse before iterating and everything is solved!

```js
// Example of array received by the function, this array is not declared in this 
// js only received as parameter. I am putting so that they can see the format
// of the data received
[{
    "id": 171659,
    "latitude": "-51.195946",
    "longitude": "-30.021810",
    "estado": "INSTALADO"
  },
  {
    "id": 171658,
    "latitude": "-51.196155",
    "longitude": "-30.021615",
    "estado": "INSTALADO"
  }
]

// My js file contains only the function that receives the data, it follows the 
// complete file. The array is not declared here, just received by the function. 
// Received successfully but can not iterate

// ====== Get Array ======
function getArray(data) {
  
  var json = JSON.parse(data); //The data enters as string was needed parse()

  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   console.log(json[i].id); // undefined
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: `var data = <your array>` maybe has something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the `data` array

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 171659,
    "latitude": "-51.195946",
    "longitude": "-30.021810",
    "estado": "INSTALADO"
  },
  {
    "id": 171658,
    "latitude": "-51.196155",
    "longitude": "-30.021615",
    "estado": "INSTALADO"
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].id);

}
```

**updated answer** using parameter.

```js
//The received array
var pass = [{
"id": 171659,
"latitude": "-51.195946",
"longitude": "-30.021810",
"estado": "INSTALADO"
  },
  {
"id": 171658,
"latitude": "-51.196155",
"longitude": "-30.021615",
"estado": "INSTALADO"
  }
]

getArray(pass);

//My function receiving date
function getArray(data){

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   console.log(data[i].id);

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clearing up, but I get the data array by parameter in my function, I edited the question

Comment: @csf see my updated answer.still same issue is there. you have not declared array . you must declare the array before pass with `getArray` function

Comment: The array is only an example of what is received by the function, this array is not declared in this js only received as parameter. I get the data successfully. I am putting the array just so they can see the format of the data received

Comment: @csf ..ok..then how to get the array ?. i m not get your point .please show more code..

Comment: I have a jsf button that calls this function and passes the array as param param. No problem in receiving array because when I make console.log (date) I can see the complete array. The problem is in the iteration that returns undefined

Comment: Thanks for the personal help! The array was entering as a string I parse before iterating and everything is solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
 {
   "id": 171659,
   "latitude": "-51.195946",
   "longitude": "-30.021810",
   "estado": "INSTALADO"
 },
  {
    "id": 171658,
    "latitude": "-51.196155",
    "longitude": "-30.021615",
    "estado": "INSTALADO"
  }
]
function getArray(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].id);
}}

getArray(data)
```

you need to assign your object in to variable and then call that variable in your function

Comment: The array is only an example of what is received by the function, this array is not declared in this js only received as parameter. I get the data successfully. I am putting the array just so they can see the format of the data received

Comment: Thanks for the personal help! The array was entering as a string I parse before iterating and everything is solved!